# Solve "Response: Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error" on AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda, pymssql

I've a pandas dataframe which I built after reading data from a SQL Server using pymssql and then do some transformation on it, works fine till here, prints data and count (when I keep the below part commented). But when I try to push the transformed data into another SQL Server using sqlalchemy, AWS Lambda Function just gives a one line Response with no hint to debug:

**Code:**

```
#Insert rows
connwrite = sql.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://abc_user:abc123@12.50.214.47:1433/testDB')
data.to_sql('test2_table', con=connwrite, if_exists='append',index=False, chunksize=10000)
print("Data Inserted successfully. Inserted Rows: " + str(datarows))
```

**AWS Lambda Function Response:**

Response:
Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error
[image]

Comment: so just querying inside the Lambda works?

Comment: Yes. Querying a DB works, writing to a DB gives this strange error which is not understandable enough.

Comment: how about writing to that particular db outside lambda?

Comment: To be honest, I tried with the first preference "PyODBC" but after struggling for 2 days on the driver issue (empty list when doing pyodbc.drivers() whereas it worked smooth on my local machine, lost hope. Used pymssql instead, but later saw, sqlalchemy when being used with pymssql for create_engine doesn't support "fast_executemany=True" as a parameter and hence it works but is extremely slow.

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue when I am trying to do the same thing. Could you share your code where you achieved the result with pymysql?